# Include statement return empty list/null Linq

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, entity

Can't get test with Questions and Answers Included, don't know why. Any thoughts? The return is null with properties Questions, Answers.
Should i hit for questions and answers to db separately?
Seach for them with testId?

Function that get test from db

```
        public Test GetSpecifiedTest(int testId)
        {
            var test = _context.Tests
                .Include(x => x.Questions)
                .Include(x => x.Answers)
                .FirstOrDefault();

            if (test == null) throw new Exception("Test not Found");

            return test;
        }
```

Test entity

```
public class Test
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public virtual List<Answer>? Answers { get; set; }
        public int Score { get; set; } = 0;
        public bool IsResolved { get; set; } = false;

        public int UserId { get; set; }
        public virtual User  User { get; set; }
        public virtual List<Question> Questions { get; set; }

    }
```

Question Entity

```
    public class Question
    {
        public Question()
        {
            this.QuestionCategories = new List<QuestionCategory>();
        }
        public int Id { get; set; }
        ...

        public virtual List<QuestionCategory> QuestionCategories { get; set; }
        public virtual List<Test> Tests { get; set; }
    }
```

Answer Entity

```
public class Answer
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
...

        public int TestId { get; set; }
        public virtual Test Test { get; set; }
    }
```

AppDbContext

```
            modelBuilder.Entity<Test>()
                .HasOne(t => t.User);

            modelBuilder.Entity<Test>()
                .HasMany(q => q.Questions)
                .WithMany(t => t.Tests);

            modelBuilder.Entity<Question>()
                .HasMany(q => q.Tests)
                .WithMany(t => t.Questions);

            modelBuilder.Entity<Answer>()
                .HasOne(t => t.Test);

            modelBuilder.Entity<Test>()
                .HasMany(t => t.Answers)
                .WithOne(a => a.Test);
```

> Blockquote

Want to get test with his all questions and answers, how can i get it, when include doesn't work?

[image: returned test]

Comment: Remove the double-binding. I have seen this glitch up mapping, just configure the relationship from one side. For instance if Test is to be treated as a root (top level) entity then add the modelBuilder relationships from Test with it's relations to Question and Answer, and remove the relationship redefinitions from Question to Test and Answer to Test. I.e. if you have `modelBuilder.Entity<Test>().HasMany(t => t.Answers).WithOne(a => a.Test)` you don't need `modelBuilder.Entity<Answer>().HasOne(t=> t.Test)` since that one is also missing the `WithMany` as well.

Answer (score 0):

At first look, it seems that it should work without any issues. I've made a quick test with sqllite and it works like a charm. I would recommend verifying in DB if the first row actually has questions and answers, if yes then maybe try to verify generated SQL command. You can do it i.e. by using logging debug data

```
protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
{
    optionsBuilder.LogTo(Console.WriteLine);
    optionsBuilder.EnableSensitiveDataLogging();
}
```

Comment: ```
      Executing DbCommand [Parameters=[@__testId_0='24'], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
      SELECT TOP(1) [t].[Id], [t].[IsResolved], [t].[Score], [t].[UserId]
      FROM [Tests] AS [t]
      WHERE [t].[Id] = @__testId_0
```
It seems to not join these tables, any idea why? this response it with include statements

Comment: Ok, i resolved it. I had EntityFramework and core at same project and that did the problem